# Select or deselect the checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I have an HTML as follow :

```
   <table class="responsive display table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
       <th>Sr No</th>
       <th>Student Code</th>
       <th>Student Name</th>
       <th>Date Of Birth</th>
       <th>Action</th>
       <th>Select&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a data-placement="left" rel="tooltip" title="Select All"><input id="checkAll" name="deleteselect[]" value="0" type="checkbox"></a></th>
     </tr>
    <form action="" method="post"></form>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1001</td>
      <td>Rohit Singhal </td>
      <td>17-4-1988</td>
      <td> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=eMarksheet-student-list&amp;action=update&amp;id=2" rel="tooltip" title="update" class="update">
          <i class="icon-pencil"></i>
        </a> &nbsp;&nbsp; 
        <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=eMarksheet-student-list&amp;action=delete&amp;id=2" onclick="return show_confirm();" rel="tooltip" title="Delete" class="delete">
          <i class="icon-trash"></i>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="deleteselect[]" value="2" type="checkbox">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1003</td>
      <td>Lisa Kurdow </td>
      <td>24-7-1965</td>
      <td> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=eMarksheet-student-list&amp;action=update&amp;id=6" rel="tooltip" title="update" class="update"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a> &nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=eMarksheet-student-list&amp;action=delete&amp;id=6" onclick="return show_confirm();" rel="tooltip" title="Delete" class="delete"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></td><td><input name="deleteselect[]" value="6" type="checkbox"></td></tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

I have a `select all` checkbox with id `checkAll` What I want is that when I click on this checkbox then it should select/deselect all the remaining check box in table

I have used the code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function (){
   $("#checkAll").change(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});
});
</script>
```

But when I click on selectAll checkbox then it does not select the checkboxes. Please help me what is missing in it ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xuhayzcn/1/ - works fine

Comment: Works fine here too -> http://jsfiddle.net/Loo8p7mk/

Comment: then what may be problem with my localhost

Comment: Add an console logging/alert in the click handelr to see whether it is getting executed

Comment: Also try `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {....})`.... and check if there is any error in the browser console

Comment: jQuery(...).prop not a function

Comment: @RohitashvSinghal Check my answer man.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get `jQuery(...).prop not a function` error, it means you are using an old version of jQuery (`< 1.6`). Very old, it is recommended to update the jQuery. Use this code then:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function (){
    jQuery("#checkAll").change(function () {
      if (this.checked)
        jQuery("input:checkbox").attr('checked', "checked");
      else
        jQuery("input:checkbox").removeAttr('checked');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @RohitashvSinghal Please upgrade jQuery.

Comment: I was posting some code in here, and the last comment was not yet posted. When I saw it then I realize what was going on, the problem was somewhere else. But you are as always very sharp, my compliments an up vote worth. So I do that. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use bellow code. I tested it's working fine.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#checkAll").change(function () {
       $("input:checkbox").attr('checked', this.checked);
     });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="responsive display table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
         <tr>
           <th>Sr No</th>
           <th>Student Code</th>
           <th>Student Name</th>
           <th>Date Of Birth</th>
           <th>Action</th>
           <th>Select&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a data-placement="left" rel="tooltip" title="Select All"><input id="checkAll" name="deleteselect[]" value="0" type="checkbox"></a></th>
         </tr>
        <form action="" method="post"></form>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1001</td>
          <td>Rohit Singhal </td>
          <td>17-4-1988</td>
          <td> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=eMarksheet-student-list&amp;action=update&amp;id=2" rel="tooltip" title="update" class="update">
              <i class="icon-pencil"></i>
            </a> &nbsp;&nbsp; 
            <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=eMarksheet-student-list&amp;action=delete&amp;id=2" onclick="return show_confirm();" rel="tooltip" title="Delete" class="delete">
              <i class="icon-trash"></i>
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="deleteselect[]" value="2" type="checkbox">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>1003</td>
          <td>Lisa Kurdow </td>
          <td>24-7-1965</td>
          <td> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=eMarksheet-student-list&amp;action=update&amp;id=6" rel="tooltip" title="update" class="update"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a> &nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=eMarksheet-student-list&amp;action=delete&amp;id=6" onclick="return show_confirm();" rel="tooltip" title="Delete" class="delete"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></td><td><input name="deleteselect[]" value="6" type="checkbox"></td></tr>
        </tbody></table>
```

Comment: I definitely doubt, having `checked="false"` will also make it checked. Can you show an example?

Comment: Man, use jQuery less than `< 1.6`

Comment: `$(this).is(":checked")` return bool value. So, it's working.

Comment: Okay, awesome! `:)` It would be nice if you could change `$(this).is(":checked")` to `this.checked`. Both mean the same. Do you understand why I am asking to change it?

Comment: Okay, Answer updated.
`this` is element while `$(this)` is object.